# constexpr qualifier added on a non constexpr function does not trigger any warning

Tags: c++, function, c++11, constexpr

Seems the compiler ignores the constexpr qualifier when it is added to a non-constexpr function.  Why is that?

The following code compiles fine and runs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string; using std::cout; using std::endl;

constexpr bool is_shorter(const string &lft, const string &rht) // this is not a constexpr function
{
    return lft.size() < rht.size();
}

int main()
{
    bool restul =  is_shorter("Hello", "World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/GNhfum no

Comment: It only works in some compilers. Better check what the standard says about it.

Comment: @AndreySemenov I have no idea why, I got compiled successfully on my machine. I'm using cmake to do all the jobs and set it to c++ 11. That might be a the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the standard allows it to do so.  [[dcl.constexpr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#5) states

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (8.20), or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object (6.6.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

So, since the function can never be a core constant expression the behavior is undefined and the compiler is not required to notify you.